# Connecting to Dataverse with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently writing a c# console application that reads a JSON file and then connects to the dataverse and inserts the data read from the JSON file to a table defined there. I found the following link, which lets me know that I have to install the Power Platform Tools (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/tools/devtools-install).

One of the prerequisites it mentions is I need Visual Studio 2019 or 2022. I only have Visual Studio 2017 and when I tried to search for the program with VS2017, I couldn't find it. I was wondering is there a program similar to Power Platform Tools for Visual Studio 2017? Or is there a different way to connect to the dataverse without needing to update to Visual Studio 2019 / 2022?

Jason

Tried searching for Power Platform Tools with Visual Studio 2017, but couldn't find it.